# ОС Linux Ubuntu в Одноклассниках не поёт музыка?

Tags: linux, ос

ОС Linux Ubuntu в браузере Google chrom на саите Одноклассники не поёт музыка?

Answer (score 1):

Chromium*

Флеш плейер установлен?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, у Вас Chromium (синий такой).

Google Chrome же можно скачать [здесь](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html).